# How to use Symbols with Mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, class

I looked everywhere not only SO,but couldn't find the answer. I found this [mongoose-model-ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560235/how-to-write-a-mongoose-model-in-es6-es2015). I am trying to use [Symbol data type.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) so the previous link does not help.

My class looks like this

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const _user_key = Symbol('key');
const _user_name = Symbol('name');
const _user_email = Symbol('email');

class User extends mongoose.Schema {
    constructor(key,name,email) {
        const user = super({
            this[_user_key] = key;
            this[_user_name] = name;
            this[_user_email] = email;              
        })        
    }
get key () {return this[_user_key]};
get name (){return this[_user_name]};
get email () {return this[_user_email]};    
};

export default mongoose.model('User', new User);
```

I run from terminal

```
            this[_user_key] = key;
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:122:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

If I try what Bergi suggested

```
class User extends mongoose.Schema {
    constructor(key,name,email) {
        const user = super(
            this[_user_key] = key;
            this[_user_name] = name;
            this[_user_email] = email;              
        )        
    }
```

I got error

```
            this[_user_key] = key;
                              ^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: That's simply a syntax error. The `{` in the `super( … )` call starts an object literal. It has nothing to do with symbols, this syntax wouldn't work if you used normal property names either.

Comment: @Bergi How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does not look related to symbols but to an actual syntax error

Did you mean

```js
super({
  [_user_key]   : key,
  [_user_name]  : name,
  [_user_email] : email,             
})
```

?